# Trouble turning on bluetooth in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I am using 12.04 LTS dual boot, and I can't use the bluetooth service in Ubuntu. It works fine with Windows 7. In Ubuntu I can turn on the bluetooth from the titlebar but when I switch on the visibility it automatically switches back (I'm using GNOME 3 environment).

All this happened after the 1st update (worked fine before then).

Comment: I hve the same issue, recently upgraded and my bluetooth dongle won't turn on. Seems like this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/985689

Comment: I found out the solution from ubuntuforumns, and it really worked for me..uninstalling and reinstalling 'bluez' solved my problem. Hope this will help you too..http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1812493

Answer (score 21):

Found an easier solution than reseting BIOS!

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

bluetooth was enabled on ubuntu 12.04.

I could do file transfer between Nexus7 and my laptop. but nexus7 stopped playing music and laptop started playing music!

Comment: Doesnt help...!

Comment: You might need to unblock the device first: Check `sudo rfkill list` to see if it's blocked, then unblock it: `sudo rfkill unblock <id>`. Now if you do `sudo rfkill list` again you will see the new device named `hci0`. You can now reset it using the above command. I needed to restart afterwards to make it work again.

Comment: I had trouble when I tried a dedicated bluetooth (Sennheiser BTD 500) audio dongle instead of my regular one and must have messed something up on my desktop. I couldn't pair my Wacom and headset again, even after reboot and `rfkill`. This one worked!

Comment: Tried but: Can't get device info: No such device

Comment: sudo rfkill unblock 0 did the trick thanks :)

Comment: Works on Kubuntu 14.04

Comment: I get this error when I run above command: `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same issue, and it turned out that Bluetooth was turned off in windows... If you use both windows and ubuntu on the same machine, try this command:

```
rfkill list all
```

If it says that Bluetooth is soft blocked then try to enable it on windows and then check again if it works on ubuntu also.

Comment: `sudo rfkill unblock <id>` to unblock the device.

Comment: I don't see any bluetooth in the list: `0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: @Rasoul the same for me; did you managed to make it work? if so, how? please

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem since I installed 12.04. I have tried many ways to install bluetooth, then changing if my bluetooth is soft blocked or not, then reinstall my bluetooth software on Ubuntu I had done it all.

But I found the BEST WAY to enable bluetooth with:

1. Restart your Ubuntu
2. Go to BIOS program (through <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> - its optional based on your computer)
3. Set the BIOS to 'reset to factory setting' usually using <kbd>F9</kbd> or else its based on your type of BIOS
4. Startup, then go to your bluetooth you will found that your bluetooth wont disabled again.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem (on 12.10), solution I found: kill blueman-applet and start it again. Run `blueman-applet &` from a terminal to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bluetooth device ,see if the bluetooth is switched off by hardware switch. If that is the case, turn the bluetooth hardware switch on.

Answer (score 0):

Setting to Factory Defaults helped me instantly with the Wireless and Bluetooth. They were shutdown in Ubuntu 13.04 for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Setting *what* to factory defaults exactly? You posted this as an answer to the original question, but perhaps  you meant to comment to an other answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```