# cannot connect my bluetooth speakers. why?

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth

I can no more connect my bluetooth speakers in 13.10.
It used to work before with 13.04.
Bluetooth is on but I can't add a new device on the bluetooth manager.
Is it broken ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed the problem.
Had also to reset one audio speaker.

Open terminal and type

`sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Change the value of `RememberPowered` from `true` to `false`

Save and reboot.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please mark your answer as such. Thanks!

Comment: Still ain't marked it as solved... :-)

Comment: You solution allows to connect the headset but it works *only in "mono" and not in "stereo" mode*