# Sound from bluetooth speaker seems to freeze often and is out of sync with the video

Tags: sound, 13.04, 13.10, bluetooth

Computer Model: Dell Inspiron N5050 (laptop).

Version of Ubuntu: Have checked in Ubuntu 13.10 and 13.04

Model of Bluetooth speaker: Bose Soundlink mini bluetooth speaker

**Description of issue:**

Issue 1: Able to pair and connect laptop to the speaker (but the connection breaks after some time and I have to remove the speaker from the laptop bluetooth and repair and reconnect).

Issue 2: When the speaker *is connected*; if I play a movie, the sound often stops (and pauses the video). Also, the sound and video are out of sync (what I see and what I hear do not match, the sound usually lagging the video).

I have no issues connecting the bluetooth speaker to my Android phone (HTC Wildfire S Android 2.3.5) and Samsung Galaxy tab 2 (10.1 inches) and viewing movies.

I have also tried the solution as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365816/cannot-connect-my-bluetooth-speakers-why)

```
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

and changed the value of `RememberPowered` from `true` to `false`.

Have installed Blueman and BlueZ.

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue, on a Dell Inspiron 7720 running Ubuntu 13.04. very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround for the sync problem: mplayer has a command-line option to adjust the delay between sound an image, so you could regain sync this way.

The command would be `mplayer -delay X /path/to/videofile` where `X` is the delay in seconds. *Negative* values of `X` mean that the image will be delayed, and *positive* values mean the sound will be delayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a current release or another Bluetooth dongle. I found that some USB dongles work better than integrated Bluetooth. I know that this somehow defeats the purpose of having Bluetooth only non-dongled hardware. :(I noticed on my laptop, that the audio delay was reduced to a minimum with 14.04.