# LXDE bluetooth gone. How do I get it back?

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, lxde

Suddenly I can't find the bluetooth icon on the LXDE system tray. I might have disabled it by mistake. How do I get it back?

I tried to open "run" from the menu and typing `bluetooth-agent` but nothing happens.

I used to disable bluetooth by right-clicking the icon and choosing "disable" (or something like that) just to save battery charge. It used to reappear on restart but now it doesn't. It's there in unity but not in LXDE.

`lsmod | grep bluetooth` gives out this
`bluetooth             202226  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm`

edit: following this question [Can't enable Bluetooth 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363401/cant-enable-bluetooth-13-10) I tried `try sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` but it did nothing

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu, which has LXDE as its desktop environment, uses `blueman-manager`. Here's something on how to disable it:

> Disable Bluetooth
>
> This is achieved by blacklisting the relevant bluetooth modules. To
>   find these, issue the following in LXterminal:
>
> `lsmod | grep bluetooth`
>
> An example out would be:
>
> `bluetooth 179900  23 rfcomm,bnep,btusb`
>
> Using the above example, you would edit the `blacklist.conf` file, again
>   using LXterminal:
>
> `gksudo leafpad /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
>
> and add the following lines to the end of the file:
>
> `blacklist rfcomm`
>   `blacklist bnep` 
>   `blacklist btusb` 
>   `blacklist bluetooth`
>
> After rebooting, issuing:
>
> `lsmod | grep bluetooth`
>
> Should not find anything.

Sources: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/FAQ/Guides#Disable_Bluetooth) and [here](https://lists.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/msg05780.html).

Comment: well thank you but I need to enable it not disable it