# Cannot enable Bluetooth anymore

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth

I shutdown my computer with bluetooth unactivate yesterday and now I cannot enable it anymore.

Here is the dmesg error:

```
[    3.017432] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    3.017449] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.017455] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.017457] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.017460] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.019161] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.019163] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.019169] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.021798] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.021806] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.021808] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  571.294000] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[  571.294884] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[  571.440922] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[  576.172231] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[  576.172291] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[  576.318224] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[  577.699734] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[  577.699799] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[  577.847666] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[  580.054792] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[  580.054813] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[  580.087772] Bluetooth: hci0 sending Intel patch command (0xfc8e) failed (-19)
[  582.086522] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc8e tx timeout
[  584.089803] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc11 tx timeout
[  590.083633] Bluetooth: hci0 exiting Intel manufacturer mode failed (-110)
```

Do you have any idea of how I can reactivate it?

Comment: Could you try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/204427/40581

Answer (score 2):

The LiveWireBT solution did the trick.

```
$ sudo rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

# The magic command is this one:
$ sudo rfkill unblock 0

$ sudo rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```