# Bluetooth problem - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Asus laptop

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, asus

I'm trying to find the driver for Bluetooth device for my Asus K450JF laptop.

I searched it in their support website, unfortunately there's no support for Ubuntu OS.

Is there any alternative way for activate bluetooth in my machine ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try with installing `sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus`

Comment: Your Bluetooth is probably blocked. Try suggested troubleshooting like in http://askubuntu.com/q/153384/40581. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.